# Are there any non-cosmetic penalties for damaging the Regalia?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Does damaging the Regalia to a certain point have any other penalties aside from cosmetic appearance (i.e., it won't run and you'll need to tow it, like when you run out of gas)?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, physical damage to the Regalia will not hinder your ability to drive it. From [here](http://www.novacrystallis.com/2016/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about-final-fantasy-xvs-car/):

> Final Fantasy XV‘s been designed so that other cars actively avoid the player. While you can crash into them, t**he Regalia won’t break after sustaining a lot of damage – only visible aspects such as a broken windshield or body damage will be available, though they have no bearing on the car’s actual performance**. Final Fantasy XV isn’t an action game like Grand Theft Auto so the car must remain functional at all times.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

While the vanilla Regalia cannot be damaged beyond repair, it's worth noting that if you fail to land the Regalia **Type-F** properly, the game will end, as the car will crash and all passengers will (presumably) die. This is explained to you before you take off for the first time, though.

Comment: I will say that there cames a point to where enough damage will penalize performance to a degree. I didn't crash, but had a extremely rough landing and it damage the Regalia enough to where a warning icon appear and max speed was only 30mph

Comment: @Wondercricket, interesting, I can't find anywhere online that says that... If you have it happen again, could you take pictures? That would definitely make sense, but I was always too lazy to manually drive, so my car was always in pristine condition (just generally pretty dirty).

Comment: @Venonmus If I can replicate it, I will definitely provide that information

Comment: Happened to me as well, definitely is a thing that can happen.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, @Vemonus's answer is correct for the Regalia not completely breaking down and require towing when enough damage has been applied.

However in rare cases, having a rough landing with the Regalia Type F will cause enough damage to turn on a warning icon while having a max speed of 30MPH.

[image]

Comment: Huh, I thought landing poorly was always lethal. How did you manage to not die?

Comment: @Vemonus I'm still wondering that myself